# morphism is epic?

Tags: category-theory

If we have three morphisms *f, g and h* between objects of a category.
Suppose *gf* = *h*. If *g* and *h* are epic, can we conclude that so is *f*  ? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Think first about surjective functions in the category of sets, see if you can prove it or find a counterexample in that special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

In category set let the domain and codomain of $h=g\circ f$ be a singleton.

Further let the codomain of $f$ have more than one element.

What can be said about being epic of $f,g,h$?